# Oil in the cooling system on S10 V-6 4.3

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, s10

2000 Chevy S10 w/4.3 V-6. The top radiator blew and began to overheat. I stopped and saw oil mixed with cooling fluid everywhere. I replaced the hose and thermostat, flushed the cooling system and refilled with water. It slowly began to overheat. Checked the radiator and found more oil in the system. Is it possible an intake gasket blew? It runs great, with no loss of power. Thanks, Art

Comment: That is most likely the case. Can still run great with loss of head gasket integrity.

Comment: Thanks @ Paulster2 . I'm hoping it's just at the intake level.

Comment: I don't remember there being an oil transfer location on the 4.3 which the intake seals. For that matter, I'm not sure there is one in the head gasket either, so I'll shut up '-)

Comment: @ Paulster2, I'm still searching, haven't started taking it apart yet.

Comment: I think I'll check the oil cooler lines that pass thru the radiator first.

Comment: Did you ever discover the root cause of the oil in the radiator?